# Xamarin : Visual Studio Mac changes RESX from Visual Studio Windows

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

Visual studio on Mac changes me the RESX file that was created in Visual studio on Windows.How can I block this?

Widnows "-"
Mac "+"

```
     /// <summary>
-    ///   A strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc.
-    /// </summary>
-    // This class was auto-generated by the StronglyTypedResourceBuilder
-    // class via a tool like ResGen or Visual Studio.
-    // To add or remove a member, edit your .ResX file then rerun ResGen
-    // with the /str option, or rebuild your VS project.
-    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0")]
-    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
-    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
+    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0")]
+    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
+    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
```

Comment: Make sure you describe the problem appropriately. That does not seem to be a RESX file, but the associated .Designer.cs file.

Comment: Yes this is AppResource.Designer.cs for dictionary

Comment: @LexLi how is this question not a clear for you. does it really matter if it is actual resx file or resx.designer.cs. it is even today still happening and it is pretty annoying.

Comment: @batmaci It of course does matter. Any *.designer.cs files are generated on the fly, so on Windows/.NET and Mac/Mono the generators can do whatever they like and lead to the differences. There is no good way to achieve consistency, so most people get used to that (ignore the changes whenever possible).

Comment: @LexLi you should concentrate on the problem instead of naming. there is an obvious difference between vs mac and vs windows. one generates something and other doesnt and works with empty designer.cs files. this is the question why Vs mac generates this files when we dont need it with VS windows

Comment: @batmaci Why accurate naming is not important? "Visual studio on Mac changes me the RESX file" is completed different from "Visual studio on Mac changes me the .designer.cs file". Anyway, enjoy your own commenting approach.